# Combine object value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery array is showing like

```
[Object { qty=1, item_id="76", add_ons="2", add_on_price:20}, Object { qty=1, item_id="76", add_ons="1",add_on_price:40}]
```

I want to make an array like this
[object{ qty=2,item_id=76,add_ons_price=60}]

I need to add the qty,add_ons_price in single object.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: only if `item_id` is same ?

Comment: Yes we have to combine if any item is same

Answer (score 1):

this will group objects based on property item_id

```
var result = {};

for (var i = 0, len = myObjects.length; i < len; i++) {
    var obj = myObjects[i];

    if (result[obj.item_id] === undefined) {
        result[obj.item_id] = [];
    }

    result[obj.item_id].push(obj);
}
```

now you can add the required values and push the result in new object

Comment: I have checked with your solution but it not total the add_ons_price .after creating an result array we need to create again another array to sum the add_ons_price.